# Proper way to create controllers under a subfolder in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have been struggling with this issue for the pas hour and I'm not sure what have I done wrong. So the case is like this. I wanted to create a controller folder go group different controllers into their groups. By default laravel projects created a controller folder structure like this

```
Http
--Controller
----Auth
```

So what I would like to do is to make something like this

```
Http
--Controller
----Auth
----Folder_a
----Folder_b
----Folder_c
```

After making my folders, the controllers in my folders are also properly namespaced like so

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Folder_a;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Use the main controller to allow extend to the main controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    */

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SomethingController extends Controller {
        /* Do something here*/
}
```

And finally in my routes.php i call the actions like such

```
Route::get('/action1/', array('as' => 'action1', 'uses' => 'SomethingController@action1'));
```

But some how when i try to navigate to that site it gives me this error

```
ReflectionException in compiled.php line 1029:
Class App\Http\Controllers\SomethingController does not exist
```

Noticed that it still go into the default folder App\Http\Controllers\ to find the controller but if I do like this

```
Route::get('/action1/', array('as' => 'action1', 'uses' => 'Folder_a\SomethingController@action1'));
```

Then everything will be fine... What have I done wrong in this case? also i have tried composer dump-autoload, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have done nothing wrong. This is the expected behavior! Laravel will search for the specified controller relative to `App\Http\Controllers` by default. So you have to specify the namespace from there. If you have many routes that lead to a controller in `Folder_a` you can use a route group to clean things up:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Folder_a'], function(){
    Route::get('/action1/', array('as' => 'action1', 'uses' => 'SomethingController@action1'));
    // more routes
});
```

Comment: I see... Thank you so much for helping me clearing things up... I thought that i missed something here and there... Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any need to group controllers in folders. You'll mostly have 1 controller for every resource and every resource is its own thing. There's nothing wrong if you have 50-100 controllers. If you put them in folders, you'll end up with that many folders, so nesting the files won't help.

Start normally and then refactor if you really need to.

Comment: I don't really agree with that. Controllers do not always handle a single resource or a resource at all. Subfolders come in handy when you have custom actions for admins (Admin\UserController), so you don't have to mess with authorization middleware in a single controller (which methods are allowed for the current user, which not?). Another example is structuring API endpoints (API\V1, API\V2 etc.). These folder structures also often match your routes (/admin/users, /api/v2) - looks like a well organized app structure to me. But as its often the case, it depends on your applications size :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I probably missed something with my answer. I was thinking more like Folder_a contains AController, Folder_b contains BController. That's why I thought it's a bad idea

Comment: Yeah you're right, in that case it wouldn't make much sense :P

Answer (score 0):

Other answer are right,  but if  you **want to delete the folder name** from the web.php, so it become

```
Route::get('/action1/', array('as' => 'action1', 'uses' => 'SomethingController@action1'));
```

1. In your controller delete **Folder_a** from namespace, so it become

   **namespace App\Http\Controllers;**
2. **composer dump-autoload**